# Java check string format and extract key-value

Tags: java, regex, string, pattern-matching

I have string format like below:

> {creationTime: 1429434844, mounted: 5, devId: 20, freeStart:1,
>   freeEnd:25, root:26, maxBlocks:10000}

How can I check a string is in the right format like above and extract all key-value pairs? All the keys should be exactly the same and in order, all values are integers. I am not good at regular expression so can someone help? Thank you.

Comment: That looks like a JSON; you might want to use a proper library to do that

Comment: @ɐuıɥɔɐɯ Not really. I am writing a filesystem checker

Comment: My problem is how to check the string in this exactly format

Comment: Exactly. We are talking in different "terms"; you said" "to check the string in that exactly format". I translate that into: "convert that JSON string into an object and make sure you have the values (or just the proper values)". Your problem, or what you are implementing, is agnostic to the overall solution

Comment: @ɐuıɥɔɐɯ Yes, I am mentioning first check the format and extract the values. For the later one, I know several methods to achieve. But for format checking, I cannot figure out the solution.

Comment: @ɐuıɥɔɐɯ Actually I am looking for sth can do both at the same time. I appreciate this if you can help

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a JSON library like Jackson. Check out this [tutorial](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes).

First create a model class for your data such as the following:

```
public class DataModel {
    private long creationTime;
    private int mounted;
    private int devId;
    private int freeStart;
    private int root;
    private int maxBlocks;

    // Getters and setters here
}
```

Then use an ObjectMapper instance to  read the value of the string and populate the member variables in the class.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // can reuse, share globally
DataModel data = mapper.readValue(dataString, DataModel.class);
```